# Setting text properties in matplotlib (condensed, expanded, and small-caps)

Tags: python, text, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a matplotlib plot with several pieces of text in it, but I have trouble setting some of the text properties to desirable values.

Specifically, I'm having trouble creating text of 'small-caps' variant and 'condensed'/'expanded' stretch.

I've tried the following python script

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.text(0.3, 0.3, "Hello!")
ax.text(0.3, 0.7, "Hello!", fontdict = {'stretch': 'ultra-expanded'})
ax.text(0.7, 0.3, "Hello!", fontdict = {'stretch': 'condensed'})
ax.text(0.7, 0.7, "Hello!", fontdict = {'variant': 'small-caps'})
plt.show()
```

and I get four pieces of text that are positioned as expected, but with no difference in style (i.e., setting the 'stretch' and 'variant' properties make no difference).

*What can I do to obtain the desired text style?*

Note that:

1. I've run the script with python2.7, python3.4, and on ipython notebook with python3; in all cases, I get the same results, with no errors or warnings.
2. Setting other properties ('family', 'size', 'style') to different values *does* change the output text.

Comment: Do the fonts you're using support those attributes? Many don't...

Comment: Hi @MattDMo, I am not sure. How can I check that?

Comment: Open the font in your operating system's font viewer utility and check.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if "small caps" are actually not supported in matplotlib (even though the documentation suggests otherwise). They have an open issue on it since 2017: [issue #8552](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8552)